# selector for multiple uibuttons in uitableviewcell

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton, selector

I'm adding the same selector for multiple `UIButtons` which are part of a `UITableViewCell` and it works only for the first one. Am I missing something?

Here's my code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSDictionary *d = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSArray *answers = [d objectForKey:@"answers"];//array of { id = 35; text = "\U03c4\U03a\U03c0\U03bf\U03c4\U03b1"; }

    UILabel *startDate = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    long long startDateEpoch = [[d objectForKey:@"startDate"] longLongValue];
    NSDate *sDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:startDateEpoch/1000];
    NSDateFormatter *startDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [startDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];

    startDate.text = [startDateFormatter stringFromDate:sDate];

    ((UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101]).text = [d objectForKey:@"subject"];

    NSArray *tags = [d objectForKey:@"tags"];
    ((UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:102]).text = [tags componentsJoinedByString:@" "];

    NSString *imageURL = [d objectForKey:@"media"];
    UIImageView *iv = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:103];
    iv.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    [iv sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]
          placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

    UIView *buttonsContainer = (UIView *)[cell viewWithTag:104];
    for(UIView *vv in buttonsContainer.subviews){
        [vv removeFromSuperview];
    }
    int index = 0;
    NSLog(@"buttonsContainer children: %d", buttonsContainer.subviews.count);
    for(NSDictionary *answer in answers){
        UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, index * 40 + (index+1)*5, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 40)];
        v.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        CGRect labelFrame = v.frame;
        labelFrame.origin.y = 0;
        UILabel *l = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:labelFrame];
        l.text = (NSString *)[answer objectForKey:@"text"];
        l.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

        UIView *bottomLine = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, v.frame.size.height - 1, v.frame.size.width, 1)];
        bottomLine.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:238.0/255.0 green:205.0/255.0 blue:103.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];

        UIButton *b = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:v.frame];

        [b addTarget:self action:@selector(answered:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [v addSubview:l];
        [v addSubview:bottomLine];
        [v addSubview:b];
        [buttonsContainer addSubview:v];

        index++;
    }  
}
```

So for example if 4 buttons are added, the selector is called only when I click on the first one. When I click on the other three nothing happens.

EDIT:
adding the `answered:` code:

```
- (void)answered:(UIButton *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"@answered");
}
```

Comment: did you tried to set a breakpoint on the selector? Could you provide its code?

Comment: All of this is within willDisplayCell rather than cellForRowAtIndexPath? 
Don't you expect some strange issues as soon as this cell gets reused?

Comment: And yes, please share the code of `self answererd:`

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answered: is not called (except the 1st one ofc) for the buttons since I put the logging in there

Comment: when you tap on the buttons that aren't invoking your answered method, can you tell if the button is actually being pressed?  (Does the text color change as you tap?)   If the button is outside the bounds of its parent it won't be tappable, even though it may render just fine (clipping turned off).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I found it. Many cudos to [TomSwift](https://stackoverflow.com/users/291788/tomswift) since his point gave me the idea to place borders on all the views in order to debug their frames size and origin.

Notice that I give to my buttons the same frame as their superviews, which is wrong since they should not have the same origin. The buttons' origin should be 0,0 since they have the same frame size as their superviews.

lessons learn for noobs like me:

- When a button does not work, place borders in order to make sure their frame is within the superview's bounds.
- Do not assign the same frame on a view and its subview. It will place it outside of the superview's bounds which in 92% of the cases brings undesirable behaviour.